# angular 2 routing unexpected behaviour

Tags: angular2-routing

[image: to see structure see this image]
I was doing exercise in Angular 2 routing and was able to create and run the project in Angular-2.
when I run the application it works fine if used 2 layer routing.
but when I increase routing layer to 3 it behaves unexpected.

There is one app module in which I am loading application.
then I have created separate modules for signin, signup and baselayout for others.
after login I want to use base layout as my app layout and want to load everything inside baselayout so that header and footer can be consistent.

and for each functionality I have created separate modules like DivisionModule, OrganizationModule and I want to load these two modules inside baselayout module but when I load any component of DivisionModule it directly loads inside app module not inside baselayout.

here is git url of my project.

https://github.com/sushilraj786/Angular.git

When I access signin or signup it works but when I try to access app/Organization/edit or app/organization/list or app/division/edit or app/division/list it loads under app module not under baseLayout module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sushil

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have only one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your app.component.html. 
Try adding one into your base-layout.component.html

Angular routing will look into your last router-outlet to load the template call by the routing. (also i saw you used only lazy loading, why ? is it something your exercice is about ?

EDIT :

Since you use lazy load module your routing file (in your lazy module) should not define the root path:

example :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
     component: IndexComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: BaseLayoutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'organization', loadChildren: 'app/organization/organization.module#OrganizationModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'division', loadChildren: 'app/division/division.module#DivisionModule'
      }
    ]
   }
];
```

Comment: Hi,

First of all thanks for your quick reply.

As you can see in the project on "app" route in baseLaylout module I have given "IndexComponent" which has <router-outlet></router-outlet> and expected route "organization/edit" should be loaded into this router outlet but instead of loading into this router outlet it loads into app module index router outlet.

Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, should have sleep longer, i have update my post.

Comment: Hi, I have used IndexComponent as baselayout entry and other modules will be loaded into this IndexComponent so I had provided router-outlet in IndexComponent.

Comment: Hi, if I don't redefine path it didn't work for me I am looking into that issue also.